# How To Refresh Chat using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm implementing text chat based on twilio api ,I have functions do the following loads the chat on click ,send message,get last message (setting interval to 1sec to update in real time) and i will add check if the data is unset do nothing else fetch last message,
I need to get the data value of the current clicked item

here is the script and the logs

```
[![<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
loadContacts();
displayChatOnclick();
setInterval(getlastmsg,1000);
}
  );
    //when the user clicks on contacts div fetch the chat history
    function displayChatOnclick(){   
$('#contacts').on('click','li',function() {
    var channel = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-channel');
    var name=$(this).closest('li').attr('data-name'); 
    console.log(channel);
    fetchChat(channel,name);
    sendmsg();
    //check if new msg is sent
});
}
    function fetchChat(channel,name){
$.ajax({
        url: 'loadchat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { channel:channel,name:name },


success: function(msg) {
                       console.log(name);
                       $('#conversation').html(msg);
                       }
});    
}
function loadContacts(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'loadcontacts.php',
            type: 'POST',


            success: function(msg) {
                                   $('#contacts').html(msg);
                                   }
          });    
}
//function to get the last msg 
function getlastmsg(){
  var channel = $('#contacts li').data('data-channel');
    var name=$('#contacts li').data('data-name'); 



    //check if channel and name is null do nothing else fetch last message

    console.log(name);




}
//function to send a msg
function sendmsg(){

      $("#send").click(function() {
          var channel=$(this).data('ch');
         var message=$("#msg").val();
              $('#msg').val('');

          console.log(msg);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmsg.php",
            data: {
                msg: message,
                channel:channel,

            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("sent");
           $('#b').append(result);
              }
        });
    });
}

</script>][1]][1]
```

Comment: Better consider WebSocket for chat application https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/index.htm

Comment: Also, please try to post a clearer problem and a better formatted code.
One way to solve your first problem is to load the content with a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and once the promise is resolved you can set the interval within ```then()``` or since you're using jQuery, you might take a look into [when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is a **pull method**: `setInterval` is not the best idea because it keeps calling your server with or without a change, imagine if you have 1000 users each one of them will send a request to the server every second.

I advise you to use a **push method** such as **SignalR**. [here is a demo for chat that you can do with small number of lines](http://philssignalrdemo.azurewebsites.net/chat)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Are you serious? So for you pull is better than push?

Comment: Sorry, just edited my response. I originally said that polling is more efficient than websockets. I realized I should have qualified the comment, since that isn't necessarily true in all cases. So I removed the comment. I would still say that websockets aren't clearly superior, even for things like chat applications. The problem is that for each user of your application, you need to maintain a connection. This doesn't necessarily scale well and can potentially be very resource intensive. Often polling can be more efficient.

Comment: But the OP case is chatting system I don’t think pull should be considered in his case, if it’s a different type of systems that needs data to come but not on real time then he reduce the interval time maybe what your saying will be the best to do

Comment: The OP is trying to debug something. I think your advice about considering a websockets solution is fine, it just doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Basil  thank you for your time please check the updated question

Comment: @Cully  thank you for your time please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var $container = $("#contacts li");
    $container.load("rss-feed-data.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $container.load('rss-feed-data.php');
    }, 9000);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response , check the updated question